# File Upload using Twitter Bootstrap, C#, asp.net and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap

link to Jasny http://jasny.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#fileupload

link to what the form looks like http://img507.imageshack.us/img507/3308/picpx.png

I am using the Jasny Javascript file upload in my boot strap project, it looks like this:

**ASP\HTML VIEW**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload"><input type="hidden">
<div class="input-append">
<div class="uneditable-input span2" runat="server" id="statment1"><i class="icon-file  
fileupload-exists"></i> <span class="fileupload-preview" style=""></span></div><span 
class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span><span 
class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file"></span><a href="#" class="btn 
fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I go about using this in the code behind to save the attached file to my server as I would using the C# asp.net File Upload?

In ASP.net C# I would normally do this in the code behind:

**ASP.net C# CodeBehind**

```
string filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("\\Document"), 
filename).ToString());
                filelocation = "Document\\" + filename;
                media = "Document";
```

The Jasny github explains how to set the layout using bootstrap  which is great as it looks really good (much better than the boring asp file upload) but How do I actually get I to post on my button click? I would really like to get this to work as I think it looks heaps nicer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you want to do this without a standard asp.net control, you will have to do some of the wiring that asp.net does for you.

Make sure your input has an id. I will set it here to myFile.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload"><input type="hidden">
        <div class="input-append">
            <div class="uneditable-input span2" runat="server" id="statment1">
                <i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i> 
                <span class="fileupload-preview" style=""></span>
            </div>
            <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input id="myFile" type="file" runat="server">
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload" >Remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your page should now have a `HtmlInputFile` control to your page. like this:

```
protected HtmlInputFile myFile;
```

Then you should be able to receive the file:

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    if (myFile.PostedFile != null)
    {
        // File was sent
        var postedFile = myFile.PostedFile;
        int dataLength = postedFile.ContentLength;
        byte[] myData = new byte[dataLength];
        postedFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, dataLength);
    }
    else
    {
        // No file was sent

    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Very well explained, I fell kinda silly now I thought it would be a lot harder than that.

Comment: @nunespascal Where should I put "if (IsPostBack.....")? in which page? in which sub?

Comment: That would be on whichever page has your HtmlInputFile control. Take a look at the control lifecycle to understand postbacks better.